How to find the minimum set of CODEOWNERS required for GitHub Pull Request approval
In our repo, we have multiple code owners for files/directories. A pull request that changes 30 files frequently requires reviews from multiple individuals before I can merge it.
How do I find the minimum set of code owners I need to ask to approve my PR before merging it?
The current approach is to examine each file's code owners and manually compile the list of required reviewers.

Bonus question 1: How to only find individuals and not groups.
Bonus question 2: How to include/exclude specific individual(s) from the list. For example, exclude engineering managers.


This can be done from the command line. Prerequisites:

GitHub CLI installed and logged in
Command-line JSON processor jq installed
A CODEOWNERS parser installed, such as https://github.com/hmarr/codeowners

Now, from the root of your git directory, given PR #12345, you can do:
gh pr view 12345 --json files \
| jq -r '.files[] .path' \
| xargs codeowners \
| tr -s ' ' | cut -f2- -d ' ' | sort -u

Source: Find required code owner approvers for a PR
